# Android: Facing Issue while sending mail without user intervention

Tags: java, android, email, gmail-api

I already read this thread [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)
and i am using the similar structure as described in this thread.
I took three jars (Mail,Activation,additional) and added GMailSender.java and JSEEProvider.java to my Project.
I am getting following error while doing that:

```
08-23 19:06:42.661    7671-7671/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.job.JobScheduler', referenced from method com.android.email.service.s.a
08-23 19:06:42.661    7671-7671/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.job.JobScheduler', referenced from method com.android.email.service.s.b
08-23 19:06:43.081    7671-7721/? E/Gmail﹕ Error finding the version of the Email provider.....
    android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.google.android.email
            at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:103)
            at com.google.android.gm.EmailMigrationService.a(SourceFile:1279)
            at com.google.android.gm.EmailMigrationService.onHandleIntent(SourceFile:219)
            at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

The code in Main Activity looks like this:

```
 GMailSender sender = new GMailSender(TagClass.DEVELOPER_EMAIL, TagClass.DEVELOPER_PASSWORD);
                        sender.sendMail(TagClass.FORGOT_CREDENTIALS_SUBJECT,
                                "Hi" + fullName + "\n\n" + TagClass.FORGOT_CREDENTIALS_BODY_USER + arrayListUsernamePassword.get(0)
                                        + "\n" + TagClass.FORGOT_CREDENTIALS_BODY_PASSWORD + arrayListUsernamePassword.get(1) +
                                        TagClass.FORGOT_CREDENTIALS_BODY_ENDING, TagClass.DEVELOPER_EMAIL,emailAddress );
```

I am sending the mail in Async Task and also added internet permission to my manifest and all the credentials i used are correct.